# <input type="text">に入っている文字列が全て見えているかどうかを判定したい

Tags: javascript

`width`が指定された`<input type="text">`で作ったテキストボックスに、ある長さの文字列が入っているとして、「その文字列が全て見えているか（溢れていないか？）」をJavaScriptで判定したいです。

何か手段があるのでしょうか？
ちなみに、フォントは等幅ではないので、文字数による判定はできないです。

最終的にやりたいことは、「文字列が溢れている場合に限り、マウスを載せるとポップアップで内容を全て表示する」という機能です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scrollWidth` と `offsetWidth` を比較することで可能です。

`offsetWidth` はボーダーとパディングの幅も含んでいるので、それは除外する必要があります。

```js
function setTooltip(event) {
  const INPUT_PADDING_BORDER = 6;
  var input1 = event.target;
  if (input1.offsetWidth - INPUT_PADDING_BORDER < input1.scrollWidth) {
    input1.title = input1.value;
  } else {
    input1.title = '';
  }
}
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', setTooltip);
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input value="hgoe" style="width:40px">
```

Comment: 私の環境の Firefox と Chrome は `scrollWidth` もパディング幅を含んでいますので、`offsetWidth` との比較で除外するべきはボーダー幅のみのようです。このスクリプトの場合、編集後は常にツールチップが表示されてしまいます。

Comment: 気になったのでMDNに当たってみたところ、[Element.clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)は[Element.scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth)と同様にpaddingは含むけれどborderは含まないようなので、borderをも含む[Element.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)ではなくこの2つを比較すると良さそうに思いました。

Answer (score 2):

アイディアの一つですが、テキストフィールドと同等のスタイルを持つ隠し要素を作成し、そのサイズをチェックするという手段が考えられます。

下記の例では、`display:none;`で隠した`span`要素に対して、`input`要素のスタイルを適用、入力値を`span`要素にコピーして`span`要素の幅をチェックしています。

入力フィールドに文字列を入力することで、動的に文字の溢れがチェックできているかと思います。
ブラウザによっては、xボタンでテキストフィールドの幅が変わるため、その際は、隠し要素の幅をそれに合わせて調整すると良いかもしれません。

```js
var text = $("#text");
var hidden = $("#hidden")
var result = $("#result");

// 隠しspan要素にinput要素のスタイルを適用
hidden.css({
 "font-family": text.css("font-family"),
 "font-size": text.css("font-size"),
 "padding": text.css("border-width"),
});

// 文字をコピーし幅をチェック
function checkVisible() {
  hidden.text(text.val());
  var msg = text.width() < hidden.width() ? "溢れている" : "溢れていない";
  result.text(msg);
}

checkVisible();

text.on("keyup", checkVisible);
```

```css
#text {
  width: 200px;
}

#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="text" type="text" value="すたっく・おーばー・ふろー"/>

<p id="result"></p>

<span id="hidden"></span>
```